# Apache Logs Settings

Tags: java, apache, logging, apache-commons-logging

I have developed a web page , that contains some automated tasks . Currently, in my access logs, I am receiving only the pages accessed by users.

How can I track, what option the user is selecting from the web page? Is it possible to get this information in the access-logs of Apache 2.2?

Please help me in resolving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can't do that by using an Apache.
You should determine custom javascript logic at frontend which will send some request with a necessary information(about chosen option) to your server.

Client ask for page-> Server returned page(logged in log file)-> Client choose some option->Ajax request is sent to server with info about chosen option-> Log to file.

Comment: Thank you Nickolas for your reply .